# dynamic plsql procedure has some issues while executing it?

Tags: stored-procedures, oracle11g

Dynamic PL/SQL procedure has some problems. I had declared a procedure which will creates a table and columns dynamically on execution of that procedure. Actually the procedure has compiled with no errors, I had to take column name for every time but the values taken only once and shows an error that column already exists.

```
declare
no_of_cols number:=&no_of_cols;
col_name varchar2(20):='&col_name';
query_state varchar2(2000);
ind number:=2;
begin
    query_state:='create table dupe(nam varchar2(10))';
    dbms_output.put_line(trim(replace(col_name,'%',' ')));
    execute immediate query_state;
    if(no_of_cols>=2)then
        for ind in 2..no_of_cols loop
            execute immediate 'alter table dupe add '||(trim(replace(col_name,'%','  '))||ind)||' varchar2(20)';  
        end loop;
    end if;
end;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, I'm not sure that I follow the point of the `trim` and `replace` calls unless you are entering a column name that contains a `%`?  When you're working with dynamic SQL, it's always a good idea to log the SQL statement before you execute it-- that makes debugging much easier.  If you log the SQL statement (even by writing it out to `dbms_output`), what is the exact statement that is throwing the error?

Comment: actually the statement **execute immediate 'alter table dupe add '||(trim(replace(col_name,'%','  '))||ind)||' varchar2(20)';** is executing perfectlt but when if we modify the above statement **execute immediate 'alter table dupe add '||(trim(replace(col_name,'%','  ')))||' varchar2(20)';** then i am getting the following error **[Error] Execution (44: 1): ORA-01430: column being added already exists in table ORA-06512: at line 12**

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see the difference between those two statements.  As I said, though, you want to log the actual SQL statement you've generated before executing it.  What is the actual SQL statement that your code is building?

Comment: don't afraid. There is the difference between in those two statements in the **first statement the index value is appended to the column name** but in the  **second statement it contains only the column name**. In this program i am creating a **dynamic table with dynamic column names** , for that case i had used **alter command to add columns to the table dupe**

Comment: If you remove the `ind`, then you'd be creating the same column for each iteration of the loop.  That would obviously cause you to try to create duplicate columns.

Comment: it is the problem. Actually _for every iteration the col_name should have to modify_  but it is same. there is a way in taking column name dynamically?

Comment: Then this appears identical to the prior question that you asked.  You cannot have SQL*Plus prompt you for values in a loop.  You can, however, write a shell script or a perl script or a Java app or an APEX app or any number of other things that prompt the user for input in a loop.

Comment: Thanks. conclusion for the above problem is that **we cannot assign column names in a plsql procedure for this we need a front end applications like java or ASP.NET or others** .

Comment: A stored procedure cannot prompt the user for anything.  The client must do any prompting, accept user input, and pass that input to the stored procedure.  You can certainly have a stored procedure that, say, takes a collection of column names as a parameter.  SQL*Plus as a client cannot prompt for values in a loop.  You could theoretically have a SQL*Plus script that recursively called itself but that would be highly unusual and a royal pain to maintain.

Comment: thanks for providing a solution for that problem